# Excel VBA - Comparing Column Data with Unique Identifiers

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck on how to approach a problem logically, since it may require 2-dimensional arrays, or perhaps I am over-thinking the issue.

I have two sheets of data. Each sheet of data has a list of unique identifiers and  a handful of dates associated with each identifier. Unfortunately (and this is where I am getting stuck), the number of dates associated with each identifier won't always be equal, so I am having difficulty comparing the dates.

For example, here is a sample from Sheet1:

```
1    |    06/08
1    |    06/15
1    |    06/16
1    |    06/17
1    |    06/22
1    |    06/23
1    |    06/30
1    |    07/01
1    |    07/05
1    |    07/06
1    |    07/07
1    |    07/12
1    |    07/15
1    |    07/18
2    |    06/24
2    |    06/30
2    |    07/05
2    |    07/06
2    |    07/07
2    |    07/08
2    |    07/14
```

And here is a sample from Sheet 2:

```
1    |    06/07
1    |    06/16
1    |    06/17
1    |    06/23
1    |    07/06
1    |    07/07
1    |    07/18
1    |    06/21
1    |    06/28
1    |    07/08
1    |    07/14
2    |    06/09
2    |    07/13
```

Basically, this is supposed to check progress by date for each identifier. The dates on Sheet1 have commitment dates when the project is supposed to be updated. The dates on Sheet2 have the dates when the project was actually updated for that sequence.

The basic logic loop is to take all of the unique identifiers and presumably store them in an array.

Then, for each unique value in that array, look at each unique date for that identifier in Sheet1. For that date in Sheet1, is there a date in Sheet2 that is equal or earlier? If so, the project was updated successfully on that date.

But here's the tricky part, that date on Sheet2 now needs to be discarded since it was "used." Now, we go to the next date on Sheet1 for that identifier. Is there another date for that identifier in Sheet2 that is equal or earlier? And so on.

Any help you can provide to translate this logic into VBA would be much appreciated! A simple comparison would be easy, but this level of complexity requires a lot more VBA than I am currently familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for VBA. Use this formula in C1 on Sheet1 and drag down for all your data:

```
=B1>=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0),2,1,1,"Sheet2")), IFERROR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0),3,1,1,"Sheet1")),0,0,ROW()-ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0),3,1,1,"Sheet1")))),TRUE),0),0)
```

This formula will return TRUE if it finds a suitable updated date and FALSE if the commitment date wasn't respected.

**EDIT**

Two additional points:

1. There is a small mistake where the formula can read 'update dates' from the following identifier. The corrected version is:

   ```
   =AND(B1>=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0),2,1,1,"Sheet2")), IFERROR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0),3,1,1,"Sheet1")),0,0,ROW()-ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0),3,1,1,"Sheet1")))),TRUE),0),0), OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0),1,1,1,"Sheet2")), IFERROR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0),3,1,1,"Sheet1")),0,0,ROW()-ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( MATCH(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0),3,1,1,"Sheet1")))),TRUE),0),0)=Sheet1!A1)
   ```
2. Both sheets need to be sorted by both identifier ('A' column) and date ('B' column)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you, and is a much more elegant solution than what I was trying to accomplish with 4 arrays and VBA.

Comment: @yutingxiang I am glad to help. If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution to the community. There is no obligation to do this.